# Swift Pause Endless SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am currently making a flappy bird clone, and have a SKAction (runActionForever) in my didMoveTOView method. However, once I die, I want to terminate that action, by which is followed a popup screen.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
     var endlessAction = SKAction.runActionForever(spawn, delay)
 }

 func died() {
     endlessAction..... ?
     screenDied.position = CGPoint(self.frame.x / 2, self.frame.y / 2)
     addChild(screenDied)
 }
```

Now, in another function, died(), how do I end this action? - so I can then make a screen popup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SKAction Class Reference : http://goo.gl/w6ZEFI

SKNode Class Reference : http://goo.gl/Wn9xGw

Adding Actions to Nodes : http://goo.gl/xR9Tfb

> To cancel actions that a node is running, call its removeAllActions method. All actions are removed from the node immediately. If a removed action had a duration, any changes it already made to the node remain intact, but further changes are not executed.
>
> Normally, you can’t see which actions a node is executing and if you want to remove actions, you must remove all of them. If you need to see whether a particular action is executing or remove a specific action, you must use named actions. A named action uses a unique key name to identify the action. You can start, remove, find, and replace named actions on a node.

If you need to remove all actions from your node, you can use the `removeAllActions` method. However, if you need to remove a specific action you need to run it with the method named `runAction:withKey:`.

If an action with the same key is already running, it is removed before the new one is added.

Also, you can use `actionForKey:` to see if an action is running on a specific node.

Then use `removeActionForKey:` to remove the action.

**PS : If you're looking to pause the actions and the node itself, you might want to look for the `paused` property on your node.**

Comment: If I may ask, if I want to fade out my pipes, and then remove them from the screen, how would I do that? Right now, I just do: SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(1)) and then pipePair.removeFromParent()

Comment: What isn't working with your following ? Note that NSTimeInterval is a type alias for Double, so you can directly use 1.0 for example. Here is a way to fade out then remove your node : http://pastebin.com/eAiJyszD